# Escaping HTML Characters/Tags in XML Payload

Tags: jsoup

I need JAVA code to handle escaping of HTML characters in XML payload. Can someone please share the code for this.

In XML payload, there is one description field having content like below-

```
<Description>&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;This is a &lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt; of the &lt;em&gt;new &lt;/em&gt;&lt;span
       style=&quot;font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;rich &lt;/span&gt;&lt;u&gt;text &lt;/u&gt;&lt;s&gt;feature &lt;/s&gt;it
       &lt;sub&gt;includes &lt;/sub&gt;as &lt;sup&gt;many &lt;/sup&gt;special characters as
       possible&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(231,76,60);&quot;&gt;test &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span
       style=&quot;background-color: rgb(46,204,113);&quot;&gt;line
       &lt;/span&gt;2&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align:
       center;&quot;&gt;Center&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align:
       center;&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: right;&quot;&gt;Right&lt;/div&gt;
</Description>
```

And we need to convert this into plain chars like below –

This is a test of the new rich text feature it includes as many special characters as possible
test line 2
Center

Right

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Text has the methods `StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4(String)` and `#unescapeHtml4(String)`for exactly this problem. Official documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-

A Google search for "Java escape HTML entity" would have easily found that information within seconds, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not resolving the purpose. I need to escape HTML characters and output should be like this <Description>This is a test of the new rich text feature it includes as many special characters as possible
test line 2
Center

Right
</Description>

Comment: Yes. That is what unescapeHtml4 does.